# How do you calculate multiple inputs at once with one button?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, foreach, onclick

My JS is working to update total item cost based on user's input of item quantity.  But my current "onclick" requires that I pass it an index position to calculate a given row.

I want to be able to update all row item totals (based on user's input quantity) all at once.  Can I do this in my existing updatePriceByProduct function below (maybe using a for loop to iterate over all rows)?  I'm not sure where to even begin.

#### HTML

```
<div class="item-info-container">

      <div class="page-header">
          <h1>Iron <br> Merchandising Shop</h1>

      </div>

        <div class="item-row">

            <div class="item-name"> <span> IronBubble-head </span>  </div>
            <div class="item-cost"> 25.00  </div>
            <div class="item-quantity"> QTY

              <input class="input-quantity">


            </div>
            <div class="item-total-price"> 0.00 </div>
            <div class="item-delete">  <button class="delete-button">Delete</button>  </div>

        </div>

        <div class="item-row">

          <div class="item-name">  <span> IronShirt </span>  </div>
          <div class="item-cost">  15.00  </div>
          <div class="item-quantity">

            <span> QTY
                <input class="input-quantity" type="text">
            </span>

          </div>
          <div class="item-total-price"> 0.00 </div>
          <div class="item-delete">  <button class="delete-        button">Delete</button>  </div>


        </div>

    <div class="calculator">
          <button class="calculate-button" onclick="updatePriceByProduct([0])"> Calculate Prices </button>
        </div>


</div>
</div>
```

#### Javascript

```
function getPriceByProduct(index){

    var stringPrice = document.getElementsByClassName("item-cost")[index].innerHTML;   //Currently getting span id, not all elements
    var numberPrice = Number(stringPrice);

    return numberPrice;

}


function createQuantityInput(index){

    var quantity = document.getElementsByClassName("input-quantity")[index].value;      //retrieve quantity of item from form
    return quantity;
}




function updatePriceByProduct(index){

    var updatedPrice =  getPriceByProduct(index) * createQuantityInput(index);
    var itemTotal = document.getElementsByClassName("item-total-price")[index].textContent = updatedPrice;


    return itemTotal;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I added a grand total div that is updated with the grand total. I also removed a span from one of the items because it made navigating to the price on each item different which makes it hard to use the same function for both items.

I removed the function from the button and instead grouped the elements being used together with an eventListener for a click event on the button.

When the button is clicked, the items array-like object is iterated over using map which produces a new array which will be populated with the individual product totals. 
The calculateTotals functions receives an item row and pulls that rows price and quantity, finds the product, sets it to that item' total and returns the price to be put in the array of prices.
The array of prices is then used to calculate the total in calculateTotal.

This approach will enable you to add more and more items and not have to change the functionality as long as you do not change the html structure of each item-row.

HTML:

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Iron <br> Merchandising Shop</h1>

</div>

<div class="item-row">

  <div class="item-name"> <span> IronBubble-head </span>  </div>
  <div class="item-cost"> 25.00  </div>
  <div class="item-quantity"> QTY

    <input class="input-quantity">


  </div>
  <div class="item-total-price"> 0.00 </div>
  <div class="item-delete">  <button class="delete-button">Delete</button>  </div>

</div>

<div class="item-row">

  <div class="item-name">  <span> IronShirt </span>  </div>
  <div class="item-cost">  15.00  </div>
  <div class="item-quantity">
    QTY
    <input class="input-quantity" type="text">

  </div>
  <div class="item-total-price"> 0.00 </div>
  <div class="item-delete">  <button class="delete-        button">Delete</button>  </div>


</div>

<div class="calculator">
  <button class="calculate-button"> Calculate Prices </button>
</div>
<div class="total">
  Grand Total: <span></span>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
//get the buttons and add an event listner for click on the calculate button
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
var calculateButton = buttons[2];
//get the total element to add to later
var total = document.querySelector('.total > span');
//items to iterate over
var itemRows = document.querySelectorAll('.item-row');

calculateButton.addEventListener('click', updatePriceByProduct);

function calculateTotals(itemRow) {
  //get the item's price and quantity
  var price = itemRow.children[1].innerHTML;
  var quantity = itemRow.children[2].children[0].value;

  var total = price * quantity;
  //set item's total to its total
  itemRow.children[3].innerHTML = total;
  return total;
}
function calculateTotal(totals) {
  var newTotal = totals.reduce(function(a,b) {return a + b});
  console.log(newTotal, 'new total');
  total.innerHTML = newTotal;

}

function updatePriceByProduct(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  //return an array with the totals from each item-row
  var prices = Array.prototype.map.call(itemRows, calculateTotals);
  //calcualte the total from the array of prices
  calculateTotal(prices);
}
```